# Excel VBA range.Address max length

Tags: excel, vba

Seems I found a limit to the length of the range.Address of 256 characters.

My code basically opens several workbooks (individually) and performs searches through the csv files for lines that meet specific criteria and copies the data (entire row) to the current workbook. Instead of copying each Row as it finds it, the code makes a list and add it to a range. The reason behind this process is to reduce the amount of time taken to copy each line individually. Row by row copying can take several minutes, copying the range takes only seconds.
This all works fine until there appears to be too many cells in the ranges. If the range.Address exceeds 256 characters, I get the following error.
Error message:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Relevant code:

```
Dim rngToAdd As Range
Set importWB = Workbooks.Open(FldrName & "\various.csv")
    ' start with header row
    Set rngToAdd = importWB.Sheets("hosts").Cells(1, 1)
For i Loop (through csv file)

    If match.. 
       Set rngToAdd = Union(rngToAdd, Cells(i, 1))
    End If
next i
    ' The line below errors when rngToAdd.Address reaches 257 characters or more

    importWB.Sheets("services").Range(rngToAdd.Address).EntireRow.Copy _
        thisWB.Worksheets("services.csv").Range("A1")
```

Content of rngToAdd.Address when error occurs.
(257 characters)

```
$A$1,$A$174:$A$177,$A$188,$A$243,$A$282,$A$557:$A$559,$A$576:$A$577,$A$602:$A$609,$A$612:$A$615,$A$667:$A$675,$A$719,$A$764:$A$765,$A$768:$A$777,$A$779:$A$784,$A$786:$A$788,$A$791:$A$792,$A$797:$A$798,$A$800,$A$805:$A$806,$A$808:$A$809,$A$869:$A$870,$A$879
```

One work around I found was to use the REPLACE function and remove the dollar signs.

```
    tmpAddress = Replace(rngToAdd.Address, "$", "")
    
    importWB.Sheets("services").Range(tmpAddress).EntireRow.Copy _
        DHSwb.Worksheets("services.csv").Range("A1")
```

Is there a better way to fix this apparent 256 character limit? Or is it really a character limit and some other issue?
I don't want this code to error out in the future if more ranges (cells) are found.

Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12527.21230) 64-bit

Comment: `rngToAdd.EntireRow.Copy`? Not sure why you're working with an address.

Comment: I do not know any other method that will provide the speed improvement over copying line by line in a loop. BigBen, is there another means to copy rows?

Comment: He means you can drop the address and work directly with the unioned range avoiding the character limit altogether.

Comment: braX,
If I store the line numbers in an array, that means I have to build a loop to process the row numbers and then copy line by line. This kind of processing is what I was getting away from by using the range. Not being an expert but more experienced coder, is there a way to process the array of line numbers similar to the range option?

Comment: Warcupine,
I have tried this. Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: If you're getting that error and not using ```.address``` then you have some other issue as well. It's kind of hard to tell in the psuedocode but it looks like you might be taking the addresses from one sheet and then creating a range using those values in another sheet, that seems likely to cause problems (though I'd think you'd get a different 1004 error).

Comment: All, Thank you for your responses. 
Warcupine,
The range is pulled from looping through the CSV (importWB) file. The range.address copy is applied to the same file (importWB) and copied to thisWB (workbook with the code).
Edit: Sorry, I keep forgetting this editor uses the Enter key to save the comments.

Comment: You definitely should not be using the address. Note, if you want to ping someone, please use the `@` before the username. You may want to [edit] your question with how you used `rngToAdd.EntireRow.Copy` (the attempt that threw the RTE 1004).

Comment: Thank you again @BigBen for the feedback.
I get that you suggest I not use the "address". I have tried various options
importWB.Sheets("services").rngToAdd.EntireRow.Copy _
        thisWB.Worksheets("services.csv").Range("A1")
importWB.Sheets("services").Range(rngToAdd).EntireRow.Copy _
        thisWB.Worksheets("services.csv").Range("A1")
Then i tried:
    rngToAdd.EntireRow.Copy _
        DHSwb.Worksheets("services.csv").Range("A1")
This appears to work, I did not know I could do that. 
Thank you for making me think twice about what you said.